# Htaccess RewriteRule long URL

Tags: .htaccess

I want to convert this URL:
    http://example.com/qwerty/user/folder/foo?id=bar
to this:
http://example.com/user/folder/foo/bar
How can I do it? Please help me, I am new with .htaccess files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html), this should be fine:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user/folder/foo/([A-Za-z]+)$ /qwerty/user/folder/foo?id=$1 [R=301,NC]
```

## Notes

1. the `NC` (no case) flag means that the rewrite rule is case insensitive.
2. If you need to add additional query string variables to the pretty link, you nead to set the `QSA` flag. for example if you want:

   http://example.com/user/folder/foo/bar?comment=1

   be interpreted as:

   http://example.com/user/folder/foo?id=bar&comment=1
3. The `R` flag allows you to specify a http redirect, with the option to include a status code.